# Login Boostrap Modal on MasterPage

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, webforms, modal-dialog

I have a Login & Register Boostrap Modal on my MasterPage.
The code is simple and works. The problem comes when user make an invalid use.
I have all validations on code behind, when user hit Login i need if its invalid, a Label show the error and popup keep alive. My Popup close everytime user hit Login, its ok or not. I tested some similar scenary in Content Pages, with registerstartupclient to call a function ShowModal, that reopen the modal. But i cant do that on MasterPage. So how can i validate input data and show a label without close the popup.
Im running Modal on Form Tag from Body because MasterPages dont allow more than one.
My Project is ASP.Net C# WebForms.

```
  <div id="logmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal contenido-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"> </i> Login</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">

                                    <%--<form id="Conectar">--%>
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" id="txtUsuario" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Usuario Web"/>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Password"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="LOGIN" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                                        </div>
                                    <%--</form>--%>
                                    <asp:Label ID="LblErrors" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Cerrar</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: How about `swal` (sweet alert js) ?

Comment: My problem is that Modal once i hit Login is closed and i cant show validation on popup. I will check but i would like to keep my actual model.

Comment: Actually, your popup does not close on clicking Login, it reloads the page which has the modal hidden by default?
I think you'll need a way to check onLoad if you have errors and if so, force the modal open with javascript.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same...why don't you use a mix of client side + server validation using ajax instead of code behind?..It's 2017 you know?

Comment: @Hackerman Well i dont know javascript to do that, just basic. So code behind is better for me, could you please show me how i can control it from cliente side in some example?

Comment: @Shadowfox when i click Login it postback the page, and modal is closed. I cant keep open. and that is my problem.

Comment: Can you post your code-behind?...maybe you can use the `jquery-validation` plugin

Comment: @Hackerman my code behind is checking if user and pass regex are right, else send a warning message.Later checking against database if credentials are right If everything is ok save sessions and you are in, else it show a warning message. Just that for login. Everything works fine, but i cant show the label once i click Login. I think i dont need another implementation, just to know how to keep alive Modal Popup when some errors occurs and its on Master Page. I know how to do in Content Pages but not work on Master Page.

Comment: Puchas @Betzero...y tiene que ser usando WebForms? cuando estamos en la era de MVC!....la major solucion que se me ocurre es usando javascript y ajax, pero tal vez si, onda, porque usas un modal para loguearte?....lo que se me ocurre es deshabilitar el comportamineto por defecto del boton login, usar ajax para verificar que todo este valido, sino estaba valido mostrar mensaje dentro del modal, si todo ok hacer el click the boton via js....

Comment: @Hackerman Ok, podrías darme un ejemplo de como armar la función llamada desde el clientclick y luego como llamar de esa funcion a la otra funcion que ejecuta el evento Button_Click.